# Usar componentes ionic en aplicación Angular

Tags: ionic2, angular

Necesitaría utilizar ciertos componentes de ionic como por ejemplo los toggle, de Ionic en una aplicación web montada en Angular 4.

¿Alguién sabe como podría llevarlo acabo?.

Un saludo.

Comment: Buenas, quieres copiar la carpeta o los archivos que contienen tu componente de tu proyecto ionic a tu proyecto web en angular 4?

Comment: Nope. Necesito usar los checkbox de ionic en mi app angular. Es decir, no tengo proyecto Ionic, solo uno angular en el que quiero usar los toggle de Ionci.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes que nada recuerda que con Ionic puedes crear una PWA ( aplicación web), no necesariamente debes compilar para ios, android o windows. 
Ionic tiene sus ventajas y desventajas, una de ellas es el cambio de los módulos ( Lazy loading) y la implementación del router. Así que muchas veces es mejor quedarse con Angular Puro, y para hacer todos los componentes de la aplicación se vean igual en cada tipo de plataforma puedes utilizar OnsenUI https://onsen.io/v2/api/angular2/

Actualmente esta con la versión 5 de angular pero ya están en planes de actualización a la versión 6.

Comment: Muy interesante. Le echaré un ojo!. Gracias!